# OpenCV CV_16F type

Tags: c++, opencv

What is the type of the elements of a `cv::Mat`, whose type is `CV_16F`?

I need to know because I need to iterate through the elements, but I don't know which iterator I should use.
For example, if the type is `CV_32F`, I use `mat.begin<float>()`.
For `CV_64F`: `mat.begin<double>()`.
What about `CV_16F`?

Comment: It's just half a bit size of floating-point type. Why do you want to use it?

Comment: @김선달 Do I have to use `CV_16F` to ask this question? Seeing it in the OpenCV codebase ([`#define CV_16F  7`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/17234f82d025e3bbfbf611089637e5aa2038e7b8/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/hal/interface.h#L80)) got me instantly curious about what type it would be based on.

Comment: @КонстантинВан `CV_16F` is a flag for half-precision floating point. OpenCV just allocates half less memory than `float`s. Rest of the part is responsible to the programmer.

Answer (score 3):

OpenCv implements a [float16_t](https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/dc9/classcv_1_1float16__t.html) class. It may be related.

This class seems to use *ushort* to store the *float16_t* data.